# Is it possible to deploy nextjs and strapi to heroku together?

Tags: deployment, next.js, strapi

I am learning Strapi and Next.js and it appears in the tutorials I am coming across that they always deploy the frontend and backend separately. Why is this? What is the benefit? Wouldn't it makes sense to have one repo for the whole project and do one deploy?
Help!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I like to work separately, because if you have a small update on the front, for example, it would not be necessary to deploy the entire application unnecessarily. These are responsibilities that, from my point of view, it is possible to deal with separately.